# Прочитать данные с файла на русском языке

Tags: android, кодировка, java

Пытаюсь прочитать с файла данные которые на русском языке, еклипс выдает в лог крякозяблики, сначала файл в `windows-1251`, все хорошо, конвертирую через `notepad++` в `UTF8` вообще не читает пишет

> Error parsing data
> org.json.JSONException: Value  of
> type java.lang.String cannot be
> converted to JSONObject

а вот так собственно я пытаюсь прочитать файл

```
public void addDataToDB() {

    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String str = new String(buffer);
        parseJson(str);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("", "Error, wtf?");
    }
}
```

И никак не получается получить нормальный русский текст из файла.

Ну а джсон я читаю вот так

```
public void parseJson(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray json_data = json.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < json_data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject data = json_data.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("", data.getString("name"));
                ManController.write(getBaseContext(), "'" + data.getString("name") + "'", "'"
                        + data.getString("barcode") + "'");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: а у тебя файл с json в какой кодировке создан?

Comment: windows 1251, когда перекодирываю в utf-8 выдает ту ошибку что в начале треда

Comment: что то я не вижу перекодирования, читай в той же кодироваке 
 InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, "win-1251"));

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то я не вижу перекодирования, читай в той же кодировке

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf); 
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is, "win-1251"));
```